# Hide XNA Window so it's not viewable

Tags: c#, xna, window, hide

I am trying to hide an XNA window (so it's not viewable, in the task bar, etc)

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Thats pretty hidden, one might wonder *why* you wish to do such a thing...

Comment: I *could* understand wanting to do this on a winforms/wpf app but on an XNA game?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a reference to "System.Windows.Forms" in your project and then add the following code wherever you want to hide the window:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form frm = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)System.Windows.Forms.Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
frm.Hide();
```

Make sure that `Window` is accessible where you use this code though.